# If Else Statement with String, Exporting to CSV

Tags: powershell

I am a powershell newbie and was creating a small script to import a list of Laptops and Workstations from a text file, pinging them to see if they are on our network and continuing to check the computer's agent status/config.

If the computer isn't online, I would like to have an out files saying $workstation is not online.

The Issue I had is getting that failure string to one CSV with the other data, I can export IF and Else separately, however it would be nice to have it on one CSV if possible.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
$workstation=Get-content C:\Scripts\workstation.txt

$forloop=ForEach ($workstation in $workstation) {

       if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $workstation -Count 1 -Quiet) {Get-Service -ComputerName $workstation | where-object {$_.Name -eq 'xxx Agent'} | select displayname, name, starttype, status |
        export-csv -Path C:\Scripts\therealdeal.c }

       Else {Write-Output "$workstation not available Out"}
       }

$forloop | Out-File C:\scripts\output.csv
```

Comment: try changing to plural to avoid variable confusion perhaps?> `$workstations=Get-content` then `($workstation in $workstations)`  Not 100% that I understand the issue however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if it were me I'd test to see what workstations are online first, then report what ones are offline, and deal with the rest.

```
#Load workstations
$workstations=Get-content C:\Scripts\workstation.txt
#Find which ones are online
[array]$OnlineWorkstations = Test-Connection -ComputerName $workstations -Count 1 -ea 4 |Select -Expand Address
#If they are not all online generate a file listing which ones are offline
If($workstations.count -gt $OnlineWorkstations.count){
    "Workstations not online:" | Set-Content C:\Scripts\Offline.txt
    $workstations | Where{$_ -notin $OnlineWorkstations} | Add-Content C:\Scripts\Offline.txt
}
#Get data from online workstations
$Results = ForEach ($workstation in $workstation) {
       Get-Service -ComputerName $workstation | where-object {$_.Name -eq 'xxx Agent'} | select displayname, name, starttype, status
}
$Results  |
    export-csv -Path C:\Scripts\therealdeal.c
```

Also, your csv file name seems to be missing the 'sv' from the extension.

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot for this. It appears you're comparing the count of the two lists and creating two separate lists based off of that